# Need help finding problem with webiopi GPIO header

Tags: raspbian, gpio, networking, wireless, relay

I'm a total noob when it comes to programming. This is my first time experiencing a raspberry pi and my first project is to be able to control my garage door from anywhere with an internet connection using a smartphone. I've found some helpful guides but I've run into a problem that I've yet to find a solution to.

[This](http://www.driscocity.com/idiots-guide-to-a-raspberry-pi-garage-door-opener/#comment-4187) is the guide I've been using lately and I can't seem to get the status of the GPIO pins to show on the WebIOPi website I created to show. There should be IN and OUT being displayed on the outer boxes, which when clicked toggle the GPIO pins allowing me to access my RPi from anywhere. Below is what is shown when I access the site.
[image: GPIO header]

The guide and every single other time I've seen WebIOPi being displayed shows the status of pins in those grey boxes.

**What I've done/used**

- Using a RPi B+
- Using a wireless WiFi dongle
- USB keyboard/mouse
- Pre-loaded SD card with Raspbian
- WebIOPi-0.7.0
- Allowed JavaScript in browser
- Connected RPi to wifi using desktop>menu>preferences>WiFi Conf.
- The guide advises using PuTTY, I haven't used that because I don't think it's necessary as it's the other guides seem to do fine without it.

Comment: Now, in programming, you usually want to break the problem down into small pieces, testing each piece individually. What you should do is to log into your device, using PuTTY or a keyboard and a screen, and start testing the GPIO setup. The way your question is posed, there are literally 100 different things that could have gone wrong, and there is no way to know witch one it is.

Answer (score 1):

I have a RPi 2 and installed WebIOPi-0.7.1 and had exactly the same negative result you see.  I ran WebIOPi from the command line and saw a bunch of errors.  When I did some google searching I found the following:

https://code.google.com/p/webiopi/issues/detail?id=97

Can you run WebIOPi from a shell and then bring up a browser and click around and see what happens?  I suspect you will get the same error.  It feels like something in WebIOPi is broken.  It might be a B+ or version 2 issue.

Comment: All the libraries which access the gpios at a low-level require changes for the Pi2.  The peripherals (which includes the gpios) have moved in the memory map.  Make sure you are using post Pi2 versions of the various third party software.

Comment: Thanks Joan ... I found the following thread and made the patch and now all is working on Pi2

http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=98981

Comment: That patch worked for me: https://github.com/doublebind/raspi